# High CPU when ALT+TAB to a Chrome tab playing YouTube video. Picture is frozen for a bit

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, cpu, youtube

So I was watching a YouTube video and I opened services.msc to check something. When I alt+tab back to the video, the picture was frozen for a bit while audio was still playing fine.
I opened Task Manager and recorded a video with my phone, because I didn't want to slow down my laptop with a screen recorder. The CPU gets to 100% and I don't think this is normal. Could you please help me?

This is the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I-Wtfpk9hUE

My laptop is Lenovo W540

- CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4800MQ CPU @ 2.70GHz
- RAM: 16GB
- GPU: Integrated Intel HD Graphics 4600
- GPU: NVIDIA Quadro K2100M
- Storage: 512GB SSD

While recording the video I had 2 Chrome extensions(for Twitch) turned on. I disabled them and the result was the same.

I've been experiencing this issue for a while now but decided to post today.

Chrome is updated to the latest version. Hardware acceleration is ON.

The video that was playing in the video was in 1440p.

Comment: Google Chrome may perform scans of your file system. If a file scan is being performed while watching a video, that might slow things down. https://www.vice.com/en/article/wj7x9w/google-chrome-scans-files-on-your-windows-computer-chrome-cleanup-tool

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I don't think this is the case here. As you can see from the video, this happens only when I switch back to the video tab.